# Compare multiple folders for file differences

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I began to compare 2 folder structures to find files that did not match by date and size, but the requirment has been changed to 4 folders and I am stuck.

So here is what I am trying to do:
We upload several hundred folders\files to 4 different servers.  The files must all match.  Sometimes a file will not copy properly.  So I need a script to read all four directories and compare all the files to make sure they match by size and date.
Output should only be a simple list that shows me the files that didn't match.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

I can do two folders but am lost on four.  Also, this output is confusing.  Not sure how to only list those that don't match.

```
    $path1 = "\\path\folder
    $path2 = "\\path\folder1
    $dif = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $path1 -DifferenceObject $path2 -Property FullName, Length, LastWriteTime
    $dif | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Do you have a "master" location? Like a location where you copied the files from and everything is correct? That would simplify it alot

Comment: I could use one as the master if needed

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it with a hash based approach, and possibly use a database table somehwere to help yourself out.  BTW, [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) has the `Get-Hash` commandlet which will help you do this.

**Basic approach**

Traverse each server's desired folder-tree (you want to do this **on** the servers involved for performance reasons, not over a network share!) and generate a hash on each file you find.  Store the hash and the full path and server name somewhere, preferrably a database table accessible from all four servers--it'll make processing much easier.

Then, if you've used a database table, write a few simple queries:

1. find any hash where there are fewer than 4 instances of the hash.
2. find any file path (you may have to process the path string to get it to the same relative root for each server ) where there are differing hashes (although this might be covered by 1. above).

All of this can be done from within PS, of course.

**Why this way of doing things may be helpful**

1. You don't have to run a four-way Compare-Object. The hashes serve as your point of comparison.
2. Your Powershell code to generate the hashes is one identical function that gets run on each server.
3. It scales.  You could easily do this for 100 folders.
4. You end up with something easily manipulated and "distributed",i.e. accesible to the servers involved--the database table.

**Downside**

PSCX Get-Hash isn't very fast.  This can easily be remedied by having PS fire [some faster hash generating command, such as this one, md5sums](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/).

**How to do without using a database table**
1. Write the hashes, file paths, severnames to files on each server as you are processing folders for hashes, and bring those files back when done.
2. Process the files into a hash table that keys on the hashcodes and counts each hash code.
3. You can have a parallel hash table (built at that same time as 2. while you pass throug the result files) that keys on each hash code to an array of paths/servers for that hash code.
4. Look for hash codes in hash table 1 with a count of less than 4.  Use parallel hash table 2 to look up hash codes found with a count less 4, to find out what the file path(s) and server(s) were.

Comment: So as to "run on the server" could I use invoke command? or would that not help performance?

Comment: You can use invoke.  Just don't run it on machine that is operating on a network share of the folder from another machine.  That'll be bad performance-wise.

Comment: Any kind of remoting is fine as long as all the code ends up running on the remote machine and doesn't report anything back to the initiating machine (other than that job is finished).  If you launch it as four separate remote jobs, they can run in parallel.  When they all are done, your script knows you can check the database table for results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remember that the `PrimaryPath` has to be a masterlocation(contents are correct). Also, be consistent with how you write the paths(if you include the `\` or not). Ex. Either use `c:\folders\folder1\` for all paths or `c:\folders\folder1`.

Compare.ps1

```
Param( 
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [alias("p")] [string]$PrimaryPath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [alias("c")] [string[]]$ComparePath
    ) 

#Get filelist with relativepath property
function Get-FilesWithRelativePath ($Path) {
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.Substring($Path.Length)
        $_
    }
}

#If path exists and is folder
if (Test-Path $PrimaryPath -PathType Container) {
    #Get master fileslist
    $Masterfiles = Get-FilesWithRelativePath (Resolve-Path $PrimaryPath).Path

    #Compare folders
    foreach ($Folder in $ComparePath) {
        if (Test-Path $Folder -PathType Container) {
            #Getting filelist and adding relative-path property to files
            $ResolvedFolder = (Resolve-Path $Folder).Path
            $Files = Get-FilesWithRelativePath $ResolvedFolder

            #Compare and output filepath to missing or old file
            Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Masterfiles -DifferenceObject $Files -Property RelativePath, Length, LastWriteTime | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | Select @{n="FilePath";e={Join-Path $ResolvedFolder $_.RelativePath}}
        } else { Write-Error "$Folder is not a valid foldername. Foldertype: Compare" }
    }

} else { Write-Error "$PrimaryPath is not a valid foldername. Foldertype: Master" }
```

Comment: yes, this might work.  I am trying to pass the folders from the command line but only seem to be able to see one folder.
Here is my code:
`Param(

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("p")]
    $PrimaryPath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("c")]
    $ComparePath)
    $master = Get-ChildItem $PrimaryPath -Recurse
    $paths = @($ComparePath)
    $paths | % { Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $master -DifferenceObject (Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -PassThru | where { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | select fullname }`

Comment: from commandline? cmd or powershell? do you mean it only checks one folder? if so, how are you calling the script and passing the parameters? I'm updating my answer to be a script with example now.

Comment: Well, I am testing with powerGUI but will be pass the parameters from a command line eventually:      -p C:\testing\folder1 -c C:\testing\folder2, C:\testing\folder3

Comment: Working now, but it doesn't seem to be going through the sub-folders and also is listing the sub folders that don't match, which I dont want any subfolders listed.  If that makes sense

Comment: Fixed the script to only check files now. My answer will not work 100% if the filenames are the same in different subfolders. To make that work it gets a bit more complicated, so if that's your situation, you should wait and try another answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: good =) as a said, if filenames are equal I don't think it will pickup every difference(ex. missing file). Still, if you have the luxury of calling one folder a master, you could just run robocopy to mirror the folder from one server to the others(this will also delete files). `robocopy \\masterlocation\folder \\copylocation\folder /MIR /SEC /SECFIX /R:2 /W:2`

Comment: Well, now I am trying to figure out how to add the missing files. Any suggestions?

Comment: add it? is the function not returning all the files, or do you mean copy the missing files to the servers ?

Comment: It is showing files that dont match by name, size, etc. but files that are missing from the compared folders

Comment: For example: c:\folder1\test.txt does not exist on c:\folder2\ but the missing file test.txt is not showing in the results

Comment: that's what I said in one of my last comments. the problem is that 1st, this script is matching on filename(bad on it's own). 2nd, if there's a missing file, then the side-indicator would be <=(and my script filters those out to remove duplicates when files are different sizes). This is why I added the recommendation to use robocopy's mirror(see comment above) to do the file copying. You make sure one server is correct(a master), and then you run robocopy to mirror the content to the remote locations one by one. It only transfers differences, so you could run it ex. every 1 hour if you want.

Comment: Would luv to but I dont do the copy, just have to confirm the files all match

Comment: Try the new script. This is my last attempt, if it doesn't work for you then someone else needs to try :P